# Varying data structure, displaying in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, datacontractserializer

imagine I have this:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(List<string>))]
[KnownType(typeof(string))]
class Something
{
    public object mail {get;set;}
}
```

Instead of having to check if mail is a List or a string and then forcing it to be a list to show it in my XAML front end... How can I do almost an if statement in the XAML so that it either uses a List or a Textblock...

Here is the xaml atm:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ContactMail"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Contact.mail}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I almost want to do (pseudo code):

```
if( GetType( Contact.mail ) == List )
{
   // Do this XAML
}
else
{
   // Do this XAML
}
```

---

### **EDIT**

I can't quite get this to work:

```
<u:ContactTemplate Content="{Binding Contact.title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    <u:ContactTemplate.PropertyListString>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox x:Name="ContactTitle"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Contact.title}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </u:ContactTemplate.PropertyListString>
    <u:ContactTemplate.PropertyString>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Contact.title}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </u:ContactTemplate.PropertyString>
</u:ContactTemplate>
```

This is my Data template selector which seems to return the correct ContactTemplate:

```
public class ContactTemplate : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate PropertyListString { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate PropertyString { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if( item.GetType() == typeof(List<string>))
        {
            return PropertyListString;
        }
        else
        {
            return PropertyString;
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried it as an `ObservableCollection`

---

**Ah, well.. I just realised the background colour was white.. and so was my text.  Thanks for the help all.**

Comment: have you tried DataTemplateSelector? - `Provides a way to choose a DataTemplate based on the data object and the data-bound element.`

Comment: @kennyzx - Thanks for the heads up... I have tried to get it to work but nothing is showing up on the screen (although no crash happening)... any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, well.. I just realised the background colour was white.. and so was my text. Thanks for the help all.

Comment: glad to hear the good news.